# "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" when I tried to web scrape

Tags: python

I tried to scrape a Facebook page by filtering the `text` key with contain the keyword of `"Pecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif)`.

Although first it was working, right now I couldn't run it again. It showed me

```
  if wanted in post.get("text", ""):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

First I thought I was banned by Facebook because I keep loop over and over again. But when I tested without `if wanted in post.get("text") :` it was working fine, so I think it was not Facebook's fault.

How can I solve this issue? Why was it working first but not now?

My code:

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
listposts = []

wanted = "Pecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif)"  # wanted post
for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=10):
    if wanted in post.get("text") :
        # print("Found", t)
        listposts.append(post)
    else:
        pass
        # print("Not found")
print(listposts)
```

Comment: The error and code you have shown are inconsistent. Are you using `if wanted in post.get("text", ""):` or `if wanted in post.get("text"):`? Only the latter can give the error `'NoneType' is not iterable`.

Comment: I tried both of it , but it still return me the same error

Comment: The point is that the code that is shown in the error message is different from the code shown below. Please make this consistent and show **only** the code which you are actually running and want to ask a question about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops require an iterable to run, e.g. a list, dictionary, `range()`, etc.

`get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=10)` is what's being passed to your only `for` loop, so this FN must be returning `None` - which is not iterable.

you can try:

```
[...]
post_list = get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=10)
print(type(post_list), post_list[:50])
for post in post_list:
  [...]
```

Update:
Since the output of `get_posts()` can be `None`, add a condition outside the `for`-loop to loop only `if post_list is not None:`

Comment: Sorry i just added in the `listposts = []` in the post.

Comment: It show me `print(type(post_list), post_list[:50])
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: then use only `print(type(post_list))` ... but where does `get_posts()` come from that it's returning a generator? (that is sometimes None)??

Comment: `get_post` is a function from a library that can scrape facebook post.  Yes sometimes the result may become None